# Converting .java back to classes.dex

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, dx

I've been playing around with reverse engineering and I am having trouble recompiling after making an edit.

I first used apktool:

```
apktool d input.apk out
apktool b out
```

I then used dex2jar to convert classes.dex to jar then used JD-GUI to extract the java files. I went in and changed one string value so that everything would still be perserved but could see if it worked, so the code should all work. So I have the folder of the .java file called 'classes' and I've tried to use DX to convert back to a dex file. I enter:

```
dx --dex classes --no-strict
```

and get these errors:
[image]

Comment: I was just wondering how this tool must be used for Android Apps piracy.

Comment: Any tool can be used for good or evil. This tool's primary purpose is for modding which is what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ordering is a little off and you need to specify directories as an absolute path for the tool to recognize them. Try

```
dx --dex --output C:/Users/SkyNet/Desktop/new_dex_file.dex C:/Users/SkyNet/Desktop/classes
```

That should make a new_dex_file.dex file on your desktop from the classes folder than is on your desktop.

Comment: That resolved both errors, thankyou. However now it's saying "noclassfiles specified". I have path to the dir holding all .java files which has subfolders, would this cause that problem?

Comment: You need to compile your java files first into .class files. See javac on how to do this.